# passing props to react component from standard html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, frontend

so I wanted to do implement a sort of thing where I can put custom attributes in HTML elements which will be taken as props by a react component. Something like:

```
function someFunction(props) {
    return <h1>props.something</h1>
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="someElement" data-something="some text"></div>
```

renders:

```
<h1>some text</h1>
```

I THINK something like this could work, but I don't think its the best approach

```
let render_div = document.getElementById("someElement")
render(<someElement something={render_div.getAttribute("data-something")}/>, render_div)
```

I'm new to react so please help me :)

PS: I'm using typescript

Comment: *"I don't think its the best approach"*. Not very likely that it is. What higher level problem are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `data-` attribute you set on an HTML element is available inside the `element.dataset` property. Keep in mind though that there's a naming conversion from dash-style to camelcase (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#name_conversion)).

What you should be able to do is something like the following:

```html
<div id="root" data-title="title" data-my-text="my-injected-text" />
```

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
const props = element.dataset; // { title: 'title', myText: 'my-injected-text' }

ReactDOM.render(App, props, rootNode);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't try it now but I think it'll work